# How do I fix these errors using DT in R?

Tags: r, dt

Here's a dataset you can use to reproduce my errors (the text column does matter):

```
theRows <- c('Row One', 'Row Two', 'Row Three', 'Row Four', 'Row Five')
x1 <- runif(5, 0, 1)
x2 <- runif(5, 0, 1)
x3 <- runif(5, 0, 1)
x4 <- runif(5, 0, 1)
x5 <- runif(5, 0, 1)
x6 <- runif(5, 0, 1)
x7 <- runif(5, 0, 1)
x8 <- runif(5, 0, 1)
x9 <- runif(5, 0, 1)
x10 <- runif(5, 0, 1)
x <- data.frame(theRows, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10)
```

I need to make two separate data tables with `x`, and each is having problems.  When I attempt to add buttons for saving as a CSV or Excel file...

```
library(DT)
datatable(x, 
          extensions = 'Buttons', 
          options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip', 
                         buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel')))
```

I get the error `The extension buttonsdoes not exist` (Yes, that typo is in the error message).

when I try to fix the text column for scrolling, like so...

```
datatable(x, extensions = 'FixedColumns', 
          options = list(dom = 't', 
                         scrollX = TRUE, 
                         fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 2, rightColumns = 0)))
```

The table renders correctly, but the column `theRows` is not fixed. No matter what number I pass to `leftColumns`, the row numbers are the only fixed column.

I'm following the code set forth in the DT documentation, so I'm confused about what's causing these problems. Can anyone advise as to what I'm doing wrong?

(This is for a shiny app, but I am having both problems when I reproduce the code outside of shiny.)

Comment: Maybe you are using the CRAN version of 'DT'

Comment: Try to install development version `devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')`

Comment: After adding the development version locally, the tables worked correctly. However, after adding devtools and running the install on the server, I'm still getting the error `The extension buttonsdoes not exist`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters suggested, you have to be running the devtools version of DT in order for these extensions to work properly.

To run the devtools version, enter `devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')` in your R console. If you receive an error message, first run `install.packages(devtools)`, and then the `devtools::` install command will work just fine.